# How to detect when Mobile Safari is closed?

Tags: mobile, mobile-safari

```
 $(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
 alert('closing');
 })
```

Above code only seems to work for desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do alerts on unload, but mobile safari doesn't seem to have beforeunload.